# Possible data leakage and traceability regarding mobile personal hotspots

Tags: wifi, mobile, phone, government, hotspot

### The question

Say, one may use a mobile phone's personal hotspot functionality to broadcast a message locally via the ESSID, like "Happy Birthday Lilian" or "Stand with Hong Kong".

Assuming such hotspots are never meant to be connected by anyone (e.g. a random string of 32 characters may be used as the password), everything that is exposed shall be the hotspot itself.

I'm never an expert in the IEEE 802.11 standards, and there're many fields returned from command `iw wlan0 scan` that I don't know of. However there seems to be one thing for sure, that a same mobile phone always has an identical MAC address in the broadcast information set.

Thus the question(s):

- Is there any data other than the MAC address that could be used to track and identify a source mobile phone from the personal hotspot's broadcast information?
- What kinds of risk may such behavior (that use a mobile phone's personal hotspot to broadcast a message) have, as from other personnel (malicious ones, etc.) or other entities (like a government).
- Any protection that one may use against such risks?

Please find below a few sample scenarios that I may think of for now, for better illustrating the case.

### Scenario #1

Assuming one day there's a personally hotspot configured with the ESSID be "Down with the CN authoritarian regime" (well this may be a little bit too long but just an example) on his/her phone, and it's noticed by an attacker who then recorded the full details that were broadcasted, including but may not limit to what's shown via `iw wlan0 scan`. The attacker may not be able to identify the person immediately but such information may be used later.

Later there may be various ways to have further information exposed, like:

- If the phone is physically acquired by the CN government.
- Or if there is`e another benign message (e.g. "Happy Thanksgiving!") broadcasted via the same phone when the person is travelling in some distant area with few people near by (thus making it possible to locate the group of few people).

Comparing the information may bring me risks since the attacker would see the same MAC accress, which links me the other day to the previous person who broadcasted the malicious (at least in some places) message.

### Scenario #2

On a phone there may be applications that share some personal information with other parties together with the device information.

I'm yet unsure how much information an application may acquire regarding a personal hotspot on the phone -- if that's much enough, one may be recognized immediately (by big companies, governments, etc.) when starting the broadcast.

Comment: You don't even need a legitimate hotspot to do this; you can use Scapy or another library/tool to broadcast 1000+ SSIDs at once, all with completely bogus low-level information.

Comment: Guess I understand exactly op's intention. A built-in functionality of most mobile phones surely belongs to a different scenario than "`scapy` or another library/tool". Take op's "Free Hong Kong" example: you may broadcast that message via your own mobile phone at a restaurant, a train station, or a supermarket; you may ask your friends to do that; you may leave the hotspot on when jogging or cycling. `scapy` surely is a good thing, but I assume op's not asking for that.